# PS4 Journey, finding the level select menu

Tags: ps4, psn, journey

I used to play [Journey](http://www.metacritic.com/game/playstation-4/journey)  on the PS3. I recently purchased a PS4, and decided to play Journey again.

While playing Journey on the PS3, I was able to hit the *Select* button in order to open a menu that allows me to return to the *Level Select* area.

On the PS4, there is no such button. I have found a way to locate the menu if I idle for somewhere around 30 seconds, but I am wondering if there is any sort of button combination that allows me to reach this menu without being idle for the predetermined amount of time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the answer.

Press the touch pad

[Controller layout](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/basic/pn_controller.html) <kbd>Button C</kbd> in the `Front View` diagram